# joining files by ip address

Tags: bash, shell, join, awk

I have two files both have list of ip addresses, mac and descriptions in different columns. Some ip addresses are in both files. I want to join these files by ip addresses such that the output file has: 
1) all ip addresses from both files and
2) Any IP which is listed in both files is followed by four columns 2 each from each file containing mac and description.

**file1:**

```
11.16.31.13     00:a0:c8:b5:c2:d5  keshav-ae1.0
10.16.31.17     f0:ad:4e:01:c5:c8  keshav-ge-2/1/5.0
108.16.31.3     4c:96:14:5d:5f:f0  keshav-ae0.0
108.16.31.4     00:0a:9c:52:74:b2  keshav-ae1.0
27.16.32.1      00:00:5e:00:01:4c  keshav-ae0.0
```

**file 2:**

```
192.16.31.10     00:25:90:cd:4e:3c  keshav-ae0.0
10.16.31.17     f0:ad:4e:01:c5:c8  keshav-ae0.0
17.16.31.2      b0:a8:6e:28:87:f0  keshav-ae0.0
108.16.31.4      00:0a:9c:52:74:b2  keshav-ae0.0
10.16.31.5      2c:36:f8:ce:65:42  keshav-ae0.0
```

**Output file should be:**

```
11.16.31.13     00:a0:c8:b5:c2:d5  keshav-ae1.0
10.16.31.17     f0:ad:4e:01:c5:c8  keshav-ge-2/1/5.0 f0:ad:4e:01:c5:c8  keshav-ae0.0
108.16.31.3     4c:96:14:5d:5f:f0  keshav-ae0.0
108.16.31.4     00:0a:9c:52:74:b2  keshav-ae1.0 00:0a:9c:52:74:b2  keshav-ae0.0
27.16.32.1      00:00:5e:00:01:4c  keshav-ae0.0
192.16.31.10    00:25:90:cd:4e:3c  keshav-ae0.0
17.16.31.2      b0:a8:6e:28:87:f0  keshav-ae0.0
10.16.31.5      2c:36:f8:ce:65:42  keshav-ae0.0
```

I have tried join with sorted files (both "sort -n" or "sort -n -t . -k 1,1 -k 2,2 -k 3,3 -k 4,4" ) but it's not giving desired output.

```
sort -n file1 > file3
sort -n file2 > file4
join -j 1 -a 1 -a 2 -e UNKNOWN file3 file4 > output
```

and output file looks like below:

```
10.16.31.17 f0:ad:4e:01:c5:c8 keshav-ge-2/1/5.0 f0:ad:4e:01:c5:c8 keshav-ae0.0
10.16.31.5 2c:36:f8:ce:65:42 keshav-ae0.0
11.16.31.13 00:a0:c8:b5:c2:d5 keshav-ae1.0
17.16.31.2 b0:a8:6e:28:87:f0 keshav-ae0.0
108.16.31.4 00:0a:9c:52:74:b2 keshav-ae0.0
192.16.31.10 00:25:90:cd:4e:3c keshav-ae0.0
27.16.32.1 00:00:5e:00:01:4c keshav-ae0.0
108.16.31.3 4c:96:14:5d:5f:f0 keshav-ae0.0
108.16.31.4 00:0a:9c:52:74:b2 keshav-ae1.0
```

Comment: `awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]" "$2" "$3}END{for (i in a){print i a[i]}}' file1 file2`

Comment: Thanks @anishsane. It works! Could you also explain how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the order of your excepted output, you can try this.

```
awk 'ARGIND<3{dic[$1]=dic[$1]" "$2" "$3}ARGIND>=3 && !($1 in a){print $1dic[$1];a[$1]}' file1 file2 file1 file2
```

**Output**

```
11.16.31.13 00:a0:c8:b5:c2:d5 keshav-ae1.0
10.16.31.17 f0:ad:4e:01:c5:c8 keshav-ge-2/1/5.0 f0:ad:4e:01:c5:c8 keshav-ae0.0
108.16.31.3 4c:96:14:5d:5f:f0 keshav-ae0.0
108.16.31.4 00:0a:9c:52:74:b2 keshav-ae1.0 00:0a:9c:52:74:b2 keshav-ae0.0
27.16.32.1 00:00:5e:00:01:4c keshav-ae0.0
192.16.31.10 00:25:90:cd:4e:3c keshav-ae0.0
17.16.31.2 b0:a8:6e:28:87:f0 keshav-ae0.0
10.16.31.5 2c:36:f8:ce:65:42 keshav-ae0.0
```

**Explanation**

`ARGIND<3` means the following statement `{dic[$1]=dic[$1]" "$2" "$3}` will only process the first 2 input files, and the statement `{dic[$1]=dic[$1]" "$2" "$3}` just put the data into dictionary(in Python) or map(in C++/Java etc.) `dic` by using ip as key and the mac with descriptions as values.

`ARGIND>=3` meas the following statement `{print $1dic[$1];a[$1]}` will handle other files exclude the first 2 files. `!($1 in a)` means the key not in dictionary `a`, so that the output will not duplicate. The statement `{print $1dic[$1];a[$1]}` just print the `ip`, `mac`, `description` and update the ip to dictionary `a`.

The third and fourth param here is just to scan file for key so that the result can output as what you want.

---

If you only want to join the table, and don't care the order of output, you can just use

`awk '{dic[$1]=dic[$1]" "$2" "$3}END{for(item in dic) print item""dic[item]}' file1 file2`

**Output**

```
17.16.31.2 b0:a8:6e:28:87:f0 keshav-ae0.0
192.16.31.10 00:25:90:cd:4e:3c keshav-ae0.0
108.16.31.3 4c:96:14:5d:5f:f0 keshav-ae0.0
108.16.31.4 00:0a:9c:52:74:b2 keshav-ae1.0 00:0a:9c:52:74:b2 keshav-ae0.0
10.16.31.5 2c:36:f8:ce:65:42 keshav-ae0.0
27.16.32.1 00:00:5e:00:01:4c keshav-ae0.0
11.16.31.13 00:a0:c8:b5:c2:d5 keshav-ae1.0
10.16.31.17 f0:ad:4e:01:c5:c8 keshav-ge-2/1/5.0 f0:ad:4e:01:c5:c8 keshav-ae0.0
```

**Explanation**
The statement `{dic[$1]=dic[$1]" "$2" "$3}` do the same thing (put the date into the dictionary `dic`) and the statement `END{for(item in dic) print item""dic[item]}` means that after every input files being processed, for each key `item` in the dictionary, do print key and value.

Comment: ordering of ip is not necessary as I can sort it later. I just want simplest command to join the two tables.

Comment: The order I mean is that you want the result keeps the order of your excepted output.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '!/^$/{ if(!a[$1]){a[$1]=$1"\t"$2"\t"$3} else {a[$1]=a[$1]"\n\t\t"$2"\t"$3} } END { for(i in a) print a[i] }' f1 f2
```

**Output:**

```
17.16.31.2      b0:a8:6e:28:87:f0       keshav-ae0.0
192.16.31.10    00:25:90:cd:4e:3c       keshav-ae0.0
108.16.31.3     4c:96:14:5d:5f:f0       keshav-ae0.0
108.16.31.4     00:0a:9c:52:74:b2       keshav-ae1.0
                00:0a:9c:52:74:b2       keshav-ae0.0
10.16.31.5      2c:36:f8:ce:65:42       keshav-ae0.0
27.16.32.1      00:00:5e:00:01:4c       keshav-ae0.0
11.16.31.13     00:a0:c8:b5:c2:d5       keshav-ae1.0
10.16.31.17     f0:ad:4e:01:c5:c8       keshav-ge-2/1/5.0
                f0:ad:4e:01:c5:c8       keshav-ae0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This [`awk`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) should help:

```
awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]" "$2" "$3}END{for (i in a){print i a[i]}}' file1 file2
```

Explanation: For every IP address, record the mac address & description. (Append it to already existing entry if any.) & print everything in the end.

If you want the arrays sorted by the IP address, add [`PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal) just before the for loop.

```
awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]" "$2" "$3}END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"; for (i in a){print i a[i]}}' file1 file2
```